# regex to only allow numbers, lets through words

Tags: html, regex, forms

```
Room Preferenc:<input type="text" name="RoomPreference"  pattern="[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)"
```

is the line of code where the regex is used, i was testing it and it allowed 'hello' to go through when it is only meant to allow integer and decimal numbers

Comment: Is your code in a form?

Comment: Just wondering what the issue was, how does hello pass here [`[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fwaG4U/1/) but not here [`\d+(\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/fwaG4U/2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only allow integers and decimal into your `input`, you can use the RegEx [`\d+(\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/I34SVa/1)

- `\d+` matches any digit 1 or more times
- `( ... )?` matches the given expression `0` or `1` time.
- `\.\d+` matches a dot and at least one digit.

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/I34SVa/1)